# Update statement in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

Consider the following Dig, Assume that all the three tables have a column **Is_Deleted** by default it is set to **0**... I want to update **Is_Deleted=1** field of **Customers** table where **CustId=2** only when the rows containing **CustId=2** and **Is_Deleted=1** in **Orders** and **OrderItems**
Tables... I dont want to use **Cascade** option.. Any suggestion

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/ms152507.75c9e4c3-260d-4b8d-8a27-b720d8f4470e(en-US,SQL.90).gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is EXISTS. I assume you want to check both Orders and OrderItems. This also means you only filter on CustID once.

```
UPDATE
   C
SET
   IsDeleted = 1
FROM
   Customers C
WHERE
   C.CustID = 2
   AND
   EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
            Orders O
        WHERE
            O.CustID = C.CustID AND O.IsDeleted = 1)
   AND
   EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM
            Orders O
            JOIN
            OrderItems OI ON O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
        WHERE
            O.CustID = C.CustID AND OI.IsDeleted = 1)
```

Comment: @gbn that works what happens if some rows in orderitems table has Is_Deleted=0 for C.CustID = 2

Answer (score 1):

Ok sounds fine... 
Do we only set the deleted flag when all the orders and all the order items associated with that customer are deleted, or only if at least 1 item is deleted.

Comment: @Anthonyv ya i ll set the deleted flag when all the orders and all the order items associated with that customer are deleted

Answer (score 0):

You can make the use of Triggers on Table - **Customers**

You can get details about triggers :

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28SQL.80%29.aspx

With Trigger you can check the Value of Updated column and depending on it you can update the data of different tables.