# Check whether a value is present in a column or not in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, loops

Hai guys,

I have a table with a column named **Is_Deleted** and my query is

```
select Is_Deleted from Stock where Stock.Mat_Id=1
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/aaaff13d8a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/aaaff13d8a.jpg)

Now i have to write a condition to check whether all values are **1** else i have to terminate my loop.. How it can be done? any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're after.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM (select DISTINCT Is_Deleted from Stock where Stock.Mat_Id=1) a WHERE Is_Deleted <> 1)
BEGIN
 -- Terminate the loop
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 -- Perform action
END
```

Comment: @Dave perfect that worked.... see my other question and try to give an answer for that also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093363/update-statement-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: @gbn your answer worked for me... It was fault on my part to ask dave to answer for that... Keep in touch..

Answer (score 1):

```
select exists(select 1 from Stock where Mat_Id = 1 and
  (is_deleted is null or is_deleted <> 1))
```

Comment: @jspcal it shows error... An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Comment: @jspcal your edited query gives me Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.

Answer (score 1):

A simple exists is all you need

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Stock.Is_Deleted = 0 AND Stock.Mat_Id = 1)
...
```

If you are looping through different Mat_Ids...

```
...
--Get first @Mat_Id
WHILE @Mat_Id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Stock.Is_Deleted = 0 AND Stock.Mat_Id = @Mat_Id)
    BEGIN
       ...
    END
    SET @Mat_Id = NULL
    --Get next @Mat_Id
END
...
```

Comment: @gbn can you give ur mail id if you wish, so that i can contact you through mail...